# Unitless variable screws up calculation

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, si-units, unit-conversion

All,
the following equation represents the budget of the specific humidity $q$ (which is the ratio of mass of the water vapor to the mass of the dry air, usually written as gram/kg or kg/kg).
$$ 
\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial t}+V.\nabla q + \omega \dfrac{\partial q}{\partial p} = -\dfrac{Q_2 \, c_p}{L_v}
$$
Where $t$ is the time in seconds, $p$ pressure in pascal, $\omega$ vertical motion in Pascal per second, $V$ is the horizontal wind velocity in meter per second, $Q_2$ is the moisture sink in Kelvin/second, $c_p$ is the heat capacity at constant pressure which equal 1004 Joule/Kelvin Kg, $L_v$ is the latent heat of evaporation which is $2.2\times 10^6$ joule/kg.

$q$ is unitless quantity yet it might screw up the calculation cause using $q$ in  gram/kg yields results different than kg/kg. Any idea how to avoid inconsistency?

the previous equation in terms of units is
$$
\dfrac{1}{seconds}+\dfrac{meter}{seconds} \dfrac{1}{meters}+\dfrac{pascal}{seconds} \dfrac{1}{pascal} = - \dfrac{Kelvin}{seconds} \dfrac{joule}{Kelvin * kg}\dfrac{kg}{Joule}
$$

Comment: You might want to elaborate on how it ruins your computation with perhaps the result you wished to obtain as it's unclear what the problem is. Also the quantity in g/kg will be a different number than it is in kg/kg by a factor of $.001$ wich should be surprising.

Comment: Have you re-written the equation in just units?

Comment: Well, g/kg and kg/kg are different units, so $q$ is not ‘unitless’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter $q$ is dimensionless but not unitless. You must maintain both dimensional and unit consistency to obtain meaningful and correct results. It is not valid to replace units of g/kg with 1 (although you can typically get away with replacing g/g or kg/kg with 1). Either carry the units through or use a conversion factor to obtain units of g/g (or kg/kg) for $q$; otherwise, you risk getting inconsistent answers by a multiple of three orders of magnitude.

Comment: You mean in case of g/g or kg/kg, the units could be simply as stated above, yet in case of g/kg or any different numerator and denominator units, then the units should be mentioned, for example if the units of $q$ is g/kg, then the units of the equation should be  $$ \dfrac{g/kg}{seconds}+\dfrac{meter}{seconds} \dfrac{g/kg}{meters}+\dfrac{pascal}{seconds} \dfrac{g/kg}{pascal} = - \dfrac{Kelvin}{seconds} \dfrac{joule}{Kelvin * kg}\dfrac{kg}{Joule}
$$, yet the units on the RHS does not balance that on the LHS

Comment: Which means you have to multiply the right side by the identity 1000 g/kg.

Answer (score 1):

If $q$ is in g/kg, then put $L_v$ in J/g, that is: multiple the R.H.S by $1000$.

Comment: $q$ is unitless, hence I think it shouldn’t be tied with $L_v$. what if I used $q$ in $kg/gram$

Comment: @Kernel just make sure the units match on each side. If they don't, you can always as a scaling factor, e.g $f = 10^{-3}\rm\,kg/g$ on the R.H.S.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, $q$ is not properly dimensionless because it is the ratio of masses of specifically distinct materials. I would keep track of these differences:

\begin{align}
[q]&=\frac{\rm kg\ H_2O}{\rm kg\ air}
\\
[c]&=\frac{\rm J}{\rm K\cdot(kg\ air)}
\\
[L]&=\frac{\rm J}{\rm kg\ H_2O}
\end{align}

Consider that the product $m_\text{water}L$ gives you an energy associated with a phase transition, while the product $m_\text{air}L$ does not have an obvious physical interpretation and is most likely a mistake.

For the question of whether “grams per kilogram” is properly dimensionless, consider the existence of the milliradian.

Comment: this is interesting, yet balancing the equation will be tricky, the $\dfrac{Q_2 c_p}{L}=\dfrac{K}{s} \dfrac{kg_{watervapor}}{J} \dfrac{J}{K. kg_{dryair}}=\dfrac{k}{s}\dfrac{kg_{watervapor}}{kg_{dryair}}$ does not equal to the units on the RHS which is $\dfrac{K}{s}$ if we assumed that the units of q is kg of water vapor per kg of dry air (which is 1).

Comment: I don’t see any unit of temperature on the left side. I see $\partial q /\partial t$ and friends with unit $\rm (kg\ H_2O)\ (kg\ air)^{-1}\ s^{-1}$ on the left. On the right, $c/L$ has unit $\rm (kg\ H_2O)\ (kg\ air)^{-1}\ K^{-1}$, so $Qc/L$ has the correct unit.

Comment: You are right.  Not sure exactly how milliradian could help us understand whether “gram per kilogram” is dimensionless.

Comment: The radian is a length per length, like your $q$ is a mass per mass. But if you plug an angle in millimeters per meter into a sine function, you’ll get a bogus answer: the dimensionless argument of the sine function is the radian, not the milliradian. Likewise you can’t switch freely between grams per kilogram versus kilograms per kilogram.

Comment: I just get an idea to  make the problem a little be more challenging. Some authors use the following form of the q equation. $$ 
\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial t}+V.\nabla q + \omega \dfrac{\partial q}{\partial p} = -\dfrac{Q_2}{L_v}
$$ where there is no $c_p$ on the RHS and $Q_2$ in this case has the units of Joule/ Kg. S, and I think that Kg is the mass of the water vapor, and the units of the  $L_v$  is the same as before, in other words, we do not have any variable, I think,  that is associated with the mass of the dry air.